# How can i configure the smtp server running for gitlab(omnibus) which running on the same machine

Tags: smtp, gitlab-omnibus

I run the smtp server and gitlab on the same machine, and i am sure the the smtp server which runs the 25 port works because i receive the mail after running the this command --echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" user@example.com. And i configure the gitlab like this in the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "localhost"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "myRootName"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "myRootPassword"
#gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "example.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = false
```

Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you run a local MTA on the gitlab server there is nothing you need to configure explicitly. The SMTP settings in the gitlab.rb are only required if you use an external server or needs special configuration.

We run gitlab on Debian 8 here with the default installation of postfix. Works out of the box. But exim4 should work just fine as well.

You DO have to configure the following properties:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@example.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'GitLab'
```